# Declaring frequently varying Android Constants

Tags: android, constants

best way declare constants in android. keeping in mind this constants vary on a monthly basis. am trying to understand how to save them by use of android endpoints but i cant figure out how my app can download and use the new constants also how i can update them

```
public static final double inflation = 0.23;
public static final double REP = 0.3;
```

my issue is this constants will fluctuate in a months time to something like

```
public static final double inflation = 0.18;
public static final double REP = 0.125;
```

my understanding is that if i declare them in a java class the users might be forced to update the app every month. what am trying to achieve is to be able to update these constants in a timely manner.

Comment: "Constants" are pre-loaded values in the memory and it cannot (should not) be modifiable once it's declared. What you are saying looks like you want to push new constants from the Internet (like updating the app), but it defeats the purpose of constants. Consider using `SharedPreferences` or `sqlite` so that users can save those downloaded values into android internal storage.

Comment: you definitely don't want to force users to update your app for something like this. instead you should have your app make remote calls out to whatever source publishes those values periodically (upon launch, at scheduled intervals, etc). depending on how frequently you choose to do this you may also want to store those values locally for re-use in Shared Preferences or a DB (as @Saehun Sean Oh has mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

this is pretty vague. i don't think there's any prescribed "best way" to implement constant values.

that being said, here's a few shots in the dark:

**Approach 1**
... a standard, well-known class with `public static` fields with the constant values

```
public final class Constants {
  private Constants() { throw new AssertionError(); }

  public static final String VALUE_1 = "some constant value";
  public static final int    VALUE_2 = 43;
}
```

**Approach 2**
... if you have well-known combinations of values, you could use a well-known enum type initialized with constant values and associated accessors for those values

```
public enum Constants {
  TYPE_1 ("some constant value", 32),
  TYPE_2 ("another constant value", 43);

  private String stringConstant;
  private int    integerConstant;

  protected Constants(String stringConstant, integerConstant) {
    this.stringConstant = stringConstant;
    this.integerConstant = integerConstant;
  }

  public String stringConstant() { return this.stringConstant; }
  public int integerConstant() { return this.integerConstant; }
}
```

**Approach 3**
... you could utilize the Gradle build system to write constant values to the generated `BuildConfig` class

(in your app's build.gradle)

```
android {
  ...
  buildConfigField 'String', 'TYPE_1', '"some constant value"'
  ...
}
```

building your project would then result in a `public static` field named `TYPE_1` in your app's generated BuildConfig class.